# Get column width to pass as chunks to parse prn file

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures

I have prn file which I need to parse. I am able to parse it by using chunks. But I am passing chunk size (Column width) manually. I want to pass that dynamically.
Approach I am looking for is to read header line and get the column width of each column. which will be integer array. Any other approach or optimization will be appriciated.

My code is:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class PrnParser {

        public void parsePrn(String inputReader, String outputWriter) {

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("..//data.prn"))); {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (line.trim().equals("")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // Method called with supplied file data line and the widths of
                    // each column as outlined within the file.

                    String[] parts = splitStringToChunks(line, 16, 22, 9, 14, 13, 8);
                    for (String str : parts) {
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public String[] splitStringToChunks(String inputString, Integer... chunkSizes) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            int chunkStart = 0, chunkEnd = 0;
            for (int length : chunkSizes) {
                chunkStart = chunkEnd;
                chunkEnd = chunkStart + length;
                String dataChunk = inputString.substring(chunkStart, chunkEnd);
                list.add(dataChunk.trim());
            }
            return list.toArray(new String[0]);
        }

    }
```

Here in this code I am using chunk sizes manually as argument of `splitStringToChunks` function

```
    String[] parts = splitStringToChunks(line, 16, 22, 9, 14, 13, 8);
```

A file can have more or less columns so I need that dynamically.

Adding `data.prn` file link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19VU29P27H-Hx4wkcHobtI84xOK3AKEHL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *... and get the column width of each column.*. "Credit Limit" lets the side down (it has a space in it), otherwise you could have reasonably easily used the headers as a width guide

Comment: Also, it has to be said that it is always incumbent on the authors of fixed record length files to provide the fields spec. It shouldn't need to be guessed or 'decoded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to below code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    private static final String DILIM_PRN = " ";
    private static final Pattern PRN_SPLITTER = Pattern.compile(DILIM_PRN);

    private static final String PAD_COLUMN = "pad";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "Name            Address               Postcode Phone         Credit_Limit Birthday";
        data = data + PAD_COLUMN;

        List<String> columnList = Arrays.stream(PRN_SPLITTER.split(data)).filter(c -> !c.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        columnList.add(PAD_COLUMN);

        List<Integer> tt = columnList.stream().map(data::indexOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        IntStream.range(0, tt.size() - 1).map(i -> tt.get(i+1) - tt.get(i)).forEach(System.out::println);

        //this gives output as 16, 22, 9, 14, 13, 8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hiren . I was looking for this. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This article can help to get the
Java: Infer Column Widths of a Fixed-Width Text File
https://dev.to/awwsmm/java-infer-column-widths-of-a-fixed-width-text-file-2hh0